# Apache Ignite multiple affinity_key in create statement

Tags: ignite

Hi peoples I want to create a table in apache ignite having two foreign keys(query index) in table.Below is the query.

```
CREATE TABLE `users_roles` (
  `users_rolesId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userId` bigint(20) ,
  `roleId` bigint(20) ,
  `createdOn` timestamp ,
  `modifiedOn` timestamp,
  `createdBy` bigint(20),
  `modifiedBy` bigint(20),
  `isActive` bit(1) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`users_rolesId`))WITH "backups=1,affinity_key=userId,affinity_key=roleId"
```

But it is giving me exception :

```
 SQL Error [1001] [42000]: Duplicate parameter: affinity_key=roleId
```

So how to specify multiple query indexes in create statements??.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. Affinity key needs to be part of primary key. In your case affinity columns are not part of primary key (although they contain the same data)
2. You can't have more than one column as affinity key column.

Affinity determines how data is distributed between nodes. You can't have two affinities at once unless you have two different tables. You will have to choose one which is more imporant to you, and do distributed joins on the other one.

In your case, I recommend making roles table replicated and ditching affinity key on `role_id`.